# How to convert date from the date fns string format to Date Object

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have a date object which is when I did stringify

```
   const date =  "2022-03-13T18:30:00.00Z"
```

Now I am trying to convert this in a format using date-fns

```
format(date, "dd MMM yyyy")
```

this returns the `string` and not the date object which will be as of the date string.

I tried with

```
format(parseISO(date), "dd MMM YYYY")
```

Still it does not work .

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: `format` never outputs a date object, it's always a string. https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format#description

Comment: try passing the returned value into new Date(result)

Comment: It sounds like you're starting with a Date object? So why stringify it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

`format` is a function that always returns a string. You cannot get it to return a `Date` object because `Date` objects are not just a way to format a string. You can read about `format` in the [date-fns documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format).
If you want to use a string to get a `date` object, you can simply use the constructor for the `Date` class. Here are some acceptable ways to instantiate a `Date` object:

```
new Date( )
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(datestring)
new Date(year,month,date[,hour,minute,second,millisecond ])
```

For your case we will use `new Date(dateString)` as you already have that. So you can simply do this:

```
const date =  "2022-03-13T18:30:00.00Z";
const dateObject = new Date(date);
```

And then you will have a `Date` object with all of the convenient methods that come with it.
Of course you do not need to use `const`, I am simply following what you have.
I would recommend reading about `Date` objects. [the Tutorialspoint page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_date_object.htm) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The datestring you show (*"2022-03-13T18:30:00.00Z"*) is simply convertable to a `Date` object. Now, to format that back to a date string you wish, try using [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat).

```js
const date =  new Date("2022-03-13T18:30:00.00Z");
const formatOptions = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit' };
const [MMM, dd, yyyy] = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(`en-EN`, formatOptions)
  .formatToParts(date)
  .filter( v => v.type !== `literal`)
  .map( v => v.value );
console.log(`${dd} ${MMM} ${yyyy}`);
```